# How to make deep link to site?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am working on my SPA project I am using AngularJS.

I need to make deep linking in my application.

here is my Url:

http://www.example.com#/contacts/

When I press button to redirect to the URL above I redirected to **Home Page** page, it seems that browser ignored this part of the URL: `/contacts/`

Here is config function of home page module:

```
angular.module("workPlan", ['damageEvent',
                            'ui.router',
                            'geomindCommon',
                            'templates',
                            'lookups',
                            'ngTouch',
                            'ui.grid',
                            'ui.grid.expandable',
                            'ui.grid.selection',
                            'ui.grid.pinning',
                            'ui.grid.resizeColumns',
                            'ui.bootstrap'
])

.config([
    "$stateProvider",
    "$urlRouterProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/MainPage");
        $stateProvider
            .state("workPlan", {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/",
                template: "<ui-view></ui-view>"
            })

         .state("workPlan.list", {
             url: "MainPage",
             templateUrl: "app/workPlan/templates/workPlanList.tmpl.html",
             controller: "workPlanListController",
             controllerAs: "list",
             resolve: {
                 filterParameters: [filterParametersResolver],
                 workPlans: ["workPlanServise", workPlanServiseResolver]
             }
         })
    }
]);
```

And here is config function of contract module:

```
 (function () {
           "use strict";

          angular.module("contracts", ["ui.bootstrap", "geomindCommon", "templates"])
        .config([
            "$stateProvider",
            function ($stateProvider) {
                $stateProvider
                    .state("contracts", {
                        abstract: true,
                        url: "/contracts",
                        template: "<ui-view></ui-view>",
                        controller: "contractsController",
                        controllerAs: "contracts"
                    })
                    .state("contracts.list", {
                        url: "/contacts/",
                        templateUrl: "app/contracts/templates/contractList.tmpl.html"
                    })
                    .state("contracts.view", {
                        url: "/:contractId",
                        templateUrl: "app/contracts/templates/contractDetails.tmpl.html"
                    });
            }
        ]);


})();
```

Any idea why it happen?And how can I make deep link ?

Comment: remove the #, that's whats causing the behaviour

Comment: Does your HomePage take care of fragment? It has to read fragment and route it to make this work.